# Are try blocks necessary or even helpful for the "zero-cost" stack unwinding strategy?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, try-catch

I came across the phrase "zero-cost" exception handling a few minutes ago and finally went to go look it up. I had seen the phrase a few times previously in an exceptions vs return codes context. Here's a short description of "zero-cost" and its alternative "setjmp/longjmp".

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gnat_ugn_unw/Exception-Handling-Control.html

> GNAT uses two methods for handling exceptions at run-time. The
>   **setjmp/longjmp method saves the context when entering a frame with an
>   exception handler**. Then when an exception is raised, the context can
>   be restored immediately, without the need for tracing stack frames.
>   This method provides very **fast exception propagation, but introduces
>   significant overhead for the use of exception handlers, even if no
>   exception is raised**.
>
> The other approach is called **“zero cost” exception handling**. With this
>   method, the compiler builds **static tables to describe the exception
>   ranges. No dynamic code is required when entering a frame containing
>   an exception handler**. When an exception is raised, the tables are used
>   to control a back trace of the subprogram invocation stack to locate
>   the required exception handler. This method has considerably poorer
>   performance for the propagation of exceptions, but there is no
>   overhead for exception handlers if no exception is raised.

(GNAT is an Ada compiler but I'm guessing the explanation above is language-agnostic.)

This helps to explain why we have `try` in the first place -- some strategies for handling exceptions require saving context upon entering the try block.

The zero-cost strategy sounds very similar to goto-style cleanup and of course we don't need `mightgoto` blocks. Do `try` blocks benefit the zero-cost strategy at all? For compilers using this strategy to implement C++ exceptions, would it make any difference if the language allowed naked `throw Exception();` statements? Is `try` just a form of comment for modern compilers?

Depending on how you build the tables, the cost of zero-cost could depend on the number and location of catch blocks but not on the number and location of try blocks.

*Soapbox: The name "zero-cost" is absurdly misleading. Why not just call it "free-lunch"?*

**Relevant:**

[Why is `try` an explicit keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238335/why-is-try-an-explicit-keyword)

Comment: Reminds me of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23238335/1782465) I asked some time ago.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're asking. You need `try/catch` to associate a block of code with its exception handlers, whatever the implementation details of how the program gets to a handler. "Zero-cost" means that there's no run-time cost to enter or leave a `try` block. It's not a free lunch: there are costs when throwing an exception, as well as some static data to support stack unwinding.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Do you really *need* the `try` to help associate with the `catch`? Isn't the relevant set of `catch` always just the next set that isn't in a deeper scope? (And if a set of catch didn't cover the exception type then go upwards.) If I'm just having a ditzy moment and there's some logical reason the `try/catch` pair is necessary to make sense of a program then I'd happily accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Angew That's exactly the thought that led to this question. It looks like the answers there pretty much cover this question too.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Exactly, a "free-lunch" is usually not free and so it would be a synonymous yet more accurate name.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: You mean, could the syntax be `{/*code block*/} catch (...) {/*handler*/}` with no `try` keyword? I suppose it could (although I'd find it rather less readable), but that's got nothing to do with the unwinding strategy. Or are you suggesting there might be some other way to associate handlers with the block of code they cover than tagging them onto that block (with or without a special keyword to mark that block)?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: "Free-lunch" would be rather confusing to anyone unfamiliar with the subtleties of English metaphor. "Zero-cost (for non-exceptional program flow)" is a perfectly reasonable description; anyone who cares about the actual costs will need more than a single sentence to describe them in any case. But the choice of name is highly opinionated, and off-topic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't mean for it to be a question about language design. Syntax checking aside, when a C++ compiler that is using zero-cost sees keyword `try`, does it care? (The "free-lunch" thing is a joke. Everything you say is true.)

Comment: @Praxeolitic: From what I have read and been taught a catch must always be preceded by a try block.  If you go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6dekhbbc(v=vs.100).aspx) and look under "Execution proceeds as follows:" it seams to say that.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: Of course the compiler cares about a `try` block. Perhaps it won't generate any code for entering or leaving the block; but it's still needed for when an exception is thrown, to identify which `catch` handler should be used, regardless of the unwinding strategy. There needs to be a way to associate handlers with a block of code; that's what `try` does.

Answer (score 1):

> Are `try` blocks necessary or even helpful for the “zero-cost” stack unwinding strategy?

Yes, `try` blocks are necessary whatever the details of the unwinding strategy. When an exception is thrown, the exception mechanism needs to identify the most recently entered `try` block in order to find the associated handlers for that block.

With a "zero-cost" strategy, the code generated for entering and leaving the block will be the same as for a regular block; the fact that it's a `try` block will only affect the static data used for stack unwinding.

> would it make any difference if the language allowed naked `throw Exception();` statements?

The language does allow that. If there's a suitable handler associated with some `try` block on the call stack, then the program jumps to that handler; otherwise, it calls `terminate()` since there's nothing to handle the exception.

> Do `try` blocks benefit the zero-cost strategy at all?

That makes no sense. They're necessary to identify the set of handlers to consider; from that point of view, they "benefit" all unwinding strategies by allowing them to work in the first place.

> Is `try` just a form of comment for modern compilers?

In principle, this could be done without a keyword to identify the block, perhaps associating any `catch` block with the preceding statement. So one might regard it as just (rather helpful) documentation.